# Background image partially disappearing when resizing browser image

Tags: html, css

I am writing a website and I have gotten everything in place with the homepage the only problem is when I resize the browser window the background image moves and parts of it disappear as the window is resized. Id like it to stay fixed in the window just have the image shrink as the window is shrunk. 
I'm sure what I am doing wrong is pretty simple but I'm pretty new to coding and can't for the life of me figure out what I need to do. Thanks to you all in advance.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


body{
background: url(Home-background.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: You can use bootstrap to do this. It would save a lot of time of writing code.

Comment: It is a normal behaviour of a background image with background-size. It seems working fine for me. To maintain aspect ratio, it hides some portion of image. If you want to display the image fully. you should use an image tag with width 100 percent and height auto. but, it won't cover full body element.

Comment: Thanks Dhananjayan. Displaying the image fully when being resized is exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

when you want cover vertical and horizontal can use this code (pay attention may be deformed this background image)

```css
body {
    background: url(Home-background.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap to do this. In between the `head` tags of your html file add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

It should work. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

should the image be full width? if yes, make sure you specify the width to be 100%

```
width: 100%;
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **width: 100%; height: 100%;** of your body tag.

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML file:

```
<img id="background-image" src="Home-background.jpg">
```

In the CSS file:

```
body {
  margin:0;
}

img#background-image {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

As a result, the background image will be fully stretched, vertically and horizontally.